# Swagger exclude "_ebean_intercept"

Tags: java, playframework, swagger

I want to exclude `_ebean_intercept` field when swagger shows payload or response model.
I cannot exclude this field on my models one by one.

How I **config swagger module** to do that? I found some knowledge but all are too old or not java.

- Playframework: 2.7
- Swagger version: `"io.swagger" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.7.1"`

Thanks in advance.